# How can I create a PVH "kernel" that will be run by qemu

Tags: qemu, boot, xen

I want a simple PVH kernel that will be loaded by qemu and the entry point started. Thus far I have my linker script:

```
ENTRY(pvh_start_addr)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 1M;
    .text : { *(.boot.text)
              *(.text) }
    . = ALIGN(4K);
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
    .notes : { *(.notes) }
}
```

and the code:

```
.section .notes, "a"
.balign 4096
.align 4
.long 4  
.long 4 
.long 18  /* XEN..PHYS32 */
.asciz "Xen"
.align 4
.long  pvh_start_addr
.long  0x101000
.align 4

.balign 16
.code64
.section            ".boot.text", "ax"

.global pvh_start_addr
pvh_start_addr:
    jmp pvh_start_addr
```

Qemu loads the elf as a PVH binary by gets the start address wrong. Anyhow, it SEG faults here:

```
qemu-5.1.0/hw/i386/x86.c:417
417     pvh_start_addr = *elf_note_data_addr;
```

Will this work or do I need other elf notes for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Your code to create the ELF note seems to have the wrong value for the size of the note descriptor field: you have ".long 4" for both the n_namesz and n_descsz fields, but although the name field is indeed 4 bytes long ("Xen\0") the descriptor is 8 bytes long on a 64-bit system (because it is the ".long  pvh_start_addr").

You might consider using some variant on the ELFNOTE macro that [Xen itself uses](http://xenbits.xen.org/docs/xtf/include_2xtf_2asm__macros_8h_source.html):

```
 #define ELFNOTE(name, type, desc)                   \
     .pushsection .note.name                       ; \
     .align 4                                      ; \
     .long 2f - 1f         /* namesz */            ; \
     .long 4f - 3f         /* descsz */            ; \
     .long type            /* type   */            ; \
 1:.asciz #name            /* name   */            ; \
 2:.align 4                                        ; \
 3:desc                    /* desc   */            ; \
 4:.align 4                                        ; \
     .popsection
```

which then allows you (assuming you've defined a constant XEN_ELFNOTE_PHYS32_ENTRY for the constant 18) to write

```
ELFNOTE(Xen, XEN_ELFNOTE_PHYS32_ENTRY, .long my_entry_label)
```

and let the macro do the work of calculating the name and descriptor sizes for you.

Comment: Why do you pass four arguments to the macro when the ELFNOTE macro just consumes three?

Comment: Just a typo/thinko -- there shouldn't be a comma after the ".long" as the whole ".long my_entry_label" is the 3rd argument to the macro. I've edited the answer to fix this.

Answer (score -1):

There is a but in qemu when it loads the ELF file. For a 64bit ELF file the alignment is still a 32 bit value.

```
uint64_t phdr_align = *(uint64_t *)arg2;
```

should probably be changed to

```
uint64_t phdr_align = *(uint32_t *)arg2;
```

Comment: I'm not sure your suggested fix is correct. The argument arg2 passed to the read_pvh_start_addr() function that I think is what you're suggesting changing is a pointer to the p_align field in the elf32_phdr or elf64_phdr structs. For a 64-bit ELF file the elf64_phdr defines p_align as an Elf64_Xword, so it's 64 bits, and casting the pointer to uint32_t* is going to do the wrong thing.