# qemu-system-i386: Error loading uncompressed kernel without PVH ELF Note

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, kernel, qemu

Im trying to boot my OS to qemu with this code:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel MyOS/mykernel.elf
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
qemu-system-i386: Error loading uncompressed kernel without PVH ELF Note
```

Here is the code i use to build:

```
i686-elf-gcc -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -g -c MyOS/start.s -o MyOS/start.o
i686-elf-gcc -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -g -c MyOS/kernel.c -o MyOS/kernel.o
i686-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -nostdlib -g -T MyOS/linker.ld MyOS/start.o MyOS/kernel.o -o MyOS/mykernel.elf -lgcc
qemu-system-i386 -kernel MyOS/mykernel.elf
```

My files:

```
kernel.c/o

start.s/o

linker.ld

mykernel.elf
```

Can anyone help? If you need the code incase if its the code's fault or something, just reply stating that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to the command line

```
-machine type=pc-i440fx-3.1
```

Source: https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=33638

Alternatively have a look at this
[How can I create a PVH "kernel" that will be run by qemu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492509/how-can-i-create-a-pvh-kernel-that-will-be-run-by-qemu)

Hope this helps

Comment: gives "kernel too old to load ramdisk" error now..

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happens if you try to run a kernel with multiboot version 2 directly with the -kernel option of qemu.

I only find support for multiboot version 1 in qemu source code ( qemu ticket tracker has an issue about this : https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/389).

So you can:

- support multiboot v1 in your kernel and load it using -kernel option
- support multiboot v2 (or other) and load it in a disk image thanks to a bootloader like grub with the -hda option. e.g.

```
mkdir -p isodir/boot/grub
cp kernel isodir/boot/
printf "menuentry \"myos\" {\n\tmultiboot /boot/kernel\n}" > isodir/boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkrescue -o disk.img isodir
qemu-system-i386 -hda disk.img
```